# Android: how to display multiple activities at the same time

Tags: android, android-activity, rom, window-managers

I'm working on a custom Android ROM that must allow multiple activities to be displayed at the same time on the screen. Something similar to what the Samsung multiwindow does.
This case is a bit different though since I have to show, let's say, 5 activities at the same time.
Think of it like having a top bar, a left bar, a bottom bar and a right bar that are always visible on the screen, and then we have a center region in which normal activities must be shown. The bars are managed by their own activities.
Question is, I have NO IDEA how to accomplish that, there must be a way since samsung did it with multiwindow but as far as I know that code is not public so I cannot dig into it.
Anyone has a clue? Anyone had to do this before?

Things I don't have to do because of project requirements:

- Not use fragments, the idea is that with this custom rom, if the user starts an android default app it's activities are shown inside the inner region
- Not use ActivityGroups, deprecated, and doesn't do what I want however.

Thanks

Comment: What is the size of the bars? Can you please post an image of what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. But it's pretty simple to visualize. Imagine I have to keep "normal" activities inside an inner region. So when someone starts an activity with startActivity(Intent) that activity is diaplayed in the inner region. The bars must be something like: Top Bar (width: full-screen, height: 80px), Left Bar (width: 100px, height: full-screen) and so on.

Comment: And what is displayed on the bars? A mini-copy of the Activity view?  _Do the activities on the bars believe they are in background or foreground?_ (In fact, you can write an app and check what happens on Samsung.)

Comment: Basically what I must achieve is having the display split into separate regions, each one displaying one activity, every activity must be in foreground. So the top bar IS an activity, the left bar IS another activity and so on.

Comment: Can you post your answer here so it can also help other? Francesco Rigoni